# Upper bound on chromatic number for some graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

I am a beginner in graph theory and I am interested in finding an upper bound for the chromatic number of the following class of graphs:

> 1. If two vertices $a$ and $b$ are adjacent in $G$, then there exist vertex $c$ such that $abc$ is a triangle graph. In other words, there exist vertex $c$ such that $c$, $a$ and $b$  are adjacent.
> 2. Every graph in this class has no complete sub-graph except $K_3$.

For example chromatic number of triangle is $\chi(G)=3$. In general, an upper bound for the chromatic number of an arbitrary graph $G$ is $\Delta(G)+1$. But this bound is not necessarily optimal for the above problem.

Is there any paper about this problem?

**Update:** Is this class of graphs planar? If not, under what additional  conditions is this class of graphs planar?

Thanks.

Comment: The complete graphs $K_n$ are in your class, so the bound $\Delta(G)+1$ is actually tight for your class.

Comment: excuse me, I forget write an important property: This class has no perfect sub-graph except $K_3$.

Comment: What do you mean by the condition 2? No graph in your class has no perfect subgraph different from $K_3$? It is bit strange: any graph with at most 4 vertices is perfect.

Comment: If $G$ is a graph and $G$ has 4 vertices, then $G$ is perfect. No?

Comment: I made a mistake. I used "perfect" instead of "complete". sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $H$ (in particular for $K_4$) there exist a constant $c(H)$ such that the chromatic number of any $H$-free graph $G$ does not exceed $c(H)\frac{d\log\log d}{\log d}$, $d=\Delta(G)$ (provided that $d>0$). It is [(conjecture 3.1.)](https://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/logf4.pdf) conjectured (or already proved? oir disproved? I do not know) that double logarithm may be removed. This is proved for $H=K_3$ by Johansson. The proof is quite difficult.

Comment: How can we compute the constant $c(H)$?

Answer (score 2):

No, not every graph in your class is planar.  Let $G$ be the graph obtained from $K_{3,3}$ by adding a new vertex that is adjacent to all vertices of $K_{3,3}$.  Since, $K_{3,3}$ is triangle free, $G$ does not contain $K_4$.  Moreover, it is clear that every edge of $G$ is contained in a triangle.

Your class of graphs does not have bounded chromatic number either.  For example, the [Mycielski Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian) are a sequence of triangle-free graphs that have arbitrarily large chromatic number.  By adding an apex vertex to the Mycielski Graphs (or performing Pat Devlin's construction) you get a sequence of graphs that have unbounded chromatic number and satisfy your conditions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. your first statement is nice and acceptable for me but i cannot accept second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

(First, welcome to graph theory)

No, there's likely not much you can say by adding your restriction (that every edge is on a triangle).

Consider for example the following construction.

Let $G$ be any graph whatsoever (and make $G$ something ugly where you feel like you have no control over the chromatic number).

Then for each edge, create a new vertex and attach it to both ends of that edge (thereby putting every edge on a triangle).

This doesn't change the chromatic number [provided $G$ wasn't bipartite] or the clique number [provided $G$ had triangles], and it changes the max degree by doubling it.  So anything you had controlling the chromatic number shouldn't involve parameters unaffected by this operation.